# php old password check from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating PHP hash password update script this script working and updating new hash password but not checking old hash password I want to create old hash password check and update new password

Here is my code

```
<?php
include("database/config.php");
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
$old_password = $_POST['old_password'];
$new_password = $_POST['new_password'];
$con_password = $_POST['con_password'];
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id= ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['user_id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result(); 
if ($stmt->num_rows >0){
$stmt->fetch();
    $hash = password_hash($_POST['old_password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    if(password_verify($_POST['new_password'],  $hash)){
    if ($new_password == $con_password) {    
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE user_id = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $hash, $_SESSION['user_id']);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo "Updated Sucessfully";
    } 
    }else {
        echo "Your new Password is not match ";
    }
 }
  }else {
    echo "Your old password is incorrect";
 }
}
?>
```

This is my HTML form

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<input name="old_password" type="password" id="old_password" value="" placeholder="Current Password" required>
<input name="new_password" type="password" id="new_password" value="" placeholder="New Password" required>
<input name="con_password" type="password" id="con_password" value="" placeholder="confirm new password" required>
 <input type="submit" name="changePass" value="change password" class="submit2" />
</form>
```

Comment: Unless you can define "old hash password" there's no way we can answer here. What type of hash? What format is it saved in? Do you have an example for the password "test"?

Comment: like this my old password $2y$10$Tl9Mdys0OgHzUQvOggVAJulAFQFPpP8Xmgt78Ikp8j0zRfbkcibsu

Comment: That should work with `password_hash` as it uses the proper format.

Comment: @previn Could you please add some logical indentation to your code?  It is quite hard to read right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing the `$old_password` from the user to the `$new_password` from the user. This is wrong. You want to compare the `$old_password` from the user to what's in the database. Then, if that succeeds, save the hash of `$new_password` to the database. Assuming you pull the result of your SELECT into an array named `$row`, something like:

```
if ($_POST['new_password'] !== $_POST['con_password']) {
    // new password and confirm password don't match, abort
} else {
    if (password_verify($_POST['old_password'], $row['password']) {
        // user gave good old password, so save the new one
        $hash = password_hash($_POST['new_password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        // UPDATE users SET password = :hash WHERE user_id = :user_id
        // bind $hash to :hash
        // bind $row['user_id'] to :user_id
    } else {
        // user gave bad old password, abort
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant understand this step   // UPDATE users SET password = :hash WHERE user_id = :user_id

Comment: @previn It's using an alternative way of binding parameters, so the equivalent from your example: `UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE user_id = ?`

Comment: That's just another way of binding values like you did with the question marks. It's the same as doing `UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE user_id = ?` but it's a little more descriptive.

Comment: `$row['password']` is just an example. It contains the `users.password` value from the database. Use [`bind_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) to store the output of the SELECT query into a variable.

Comment: thanks you very much Alex Howansky brother it's working very well again thanks you